# Underground realm hid away from the Black Plague, modern boy swims there through a lake, finds a temple with a fire being

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember someone lent me this book maybe around 2000, at least not much earlier. I only remember the outline of the novel, all details are now lost to me. I read the book translated to Finnish.

It is a fantasy novel (in two parts I think) in which a boy for some reason enters a cave/tunnel of sorts, in which there is a lake. Diving into the lake, gravity goes upside down and upon reaching the bottom he actually reaches another surface. He enters an underground realm inhabited by people who hid away from the Black Plague centuries ago. They have warriors and there are some magical elements too - there is a temple/pyramid/whatever with a fearsome fire being inside.

There is some commotion and chaos erupts; I think the fire demon escapes and goes on a rampage. The boy escapes back to his own world but the warriors follow him into his home. For some reason they enter a car together and the boy, taking advantage of the warriors' ignorance of the modern world, brings the car to a halt very abruptly (he's the only one wearing a seatbelt), and escapes. I think finally he is caught, though.

Then it is revealed that the boy's father, who until now had been an absent figure, had actually once been the leader of this underground society. Now, in order to calm the mighty being of fire a sacrifice is needed, and the father stays to assume his responsibility as a leader, while the boy goes back home.

Comment: This is sort of making me think of *Tunnels*, but it doesn't have the fantasy elements.

Comment: I was going to suggest _Tunnels_ as well, but thinking about it it doesn't quite fit. As I remember that started off with the discovery of a long abandoned Tube station.

Comment: I checked the Wikipedia article on Tunnels and for a moment I doubted myself, as some elements of the plot do indeed seem similar, but unfortunately it's not the one. And I'm quite positive the book I'm searching for was published earlier, I must've been around 10 or 12 years old at the time I read it, at least not much more, and I turned 13 in 2000.